# Saving point clouds to pcd files with librealsense

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I wanted to ask if there is any implementation to save live point clouds to disk as pcd files using librealsense.

Answer (score 0):

A [librealsense grabber](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/pull/1633) and viewer was developed for PCL.

Combine that with:

- http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php
- http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd

or

- https://www.joshmcculloch.nz/#!realsense